# AWS ALB + Django + Gunicorn +- Nginx?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, nginx, gunicorn, amazon-elb

I am building an environment in AWS to host a django application. I am trying to figure out if I should be using nginx as part of the build.

I am listing a few different environments below for example/comparison purposes. All environments make use of an AWS ALB.

**ENV 1**

ALB -> dockercontainer running django

- +uses inbuilt django webserver, static files working
- -inbuilt django webserver not made for production use

**ENV 2**

ALB -> dockercontainer running django/gunicorn

- +uses gunicorn (not django webserver)
- -static files NOT working

**ENV 3**

ALB -> dockercontainer running django/gunicorn + nginx

note: I have not tested this configuration yet.

- +uses gunicorn (not django webserver)
- +uses nginx
- static files should work

I read [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/331256/why-do-i-need-nginx-and-something-like-gunicorn) stackoverflow post and understand the differing roles of gunicorn vs nginx.

I am being advised by a colleague that ENV 2 is all I need, that I should be able to serve static files with it, that the ALB provides similar functionality to NGINX. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to clarify - "ALB" stands for Application Load Balancer, which is differentiated from the older Elastic Load Balancer in that traffic can be routed based on URI.

However, whichever load balancer you're referring to, I believe you'll need nginx in the mix, as AWS load balancers don't offer any file serving capability. If your static files have a consistent URI pattern, you might be able to use an ALB to serve static files from S3 or CloudFront.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I ended up adding whitenoise to my project to handle the static files. Works ok and a lot simpler than adding nginx. Unsure of any "bad" implications from this choice but will do the job for now.

Comment: Hi @James - 3 years later, can you share if this was a good idea? We plan to deploy a flask-based app server with gunicorn behind AWS ALB, and I was wondering if I need nginx.