# Gunicorn behind AWS ALB without nginx

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, aws-application-load-balancer

We plan to deploy a [flask](https://palletsprojects.com/p/flask/)-based Python server, using [Gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org) as the server.

Gunicorn recommends using nginx as a reverse proxy, but we use AWS ALB (Application Load Balancer) so I was wondering if I can skip nginx. We don't need serving static files, so that's not an issue (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50495003/38557).

Since ALB is doing TLS-termination (among other things), is there an inherent reason to use nginx?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can avoid using Nginx. ALBs offer protection against DDoS attacks (as well as the TLS termination you mentioned).

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/aws-best-practices-ddos-resiliency/elastic-load-balancing-bp6.html

You could use Nginx to provide Gzip compression if payload size is a concern.

I'd lean towards keeping it simple and omitting Nginx. Avoiding it means one less thing to have to worry about configuring and maintaining as well as one less thing to go wrong!